# What are the benefits of using Hyperspace indexes over Z-ordering in deltaLake?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, z-order

I have streaming data in Azure Databricks being stored in delta table format. For optimization,I am currently using Z-ordering. Are there any benefits of using Hyperspace indexing subsytem over Z-ordering?

Comment: I believe that is the valid question - it's not about "what is better", but what could be the benefits of using it

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didn't use Hyperspace myself, just read documentation & code examples.

Hyperspace by functionality is closer to the [Data Skipping](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#data-skipping) functionality of the Databricks Delta implementation - it allows to read only that data that is necessary. But on Databricks, indexing of data happens automatically when they are written, while with Hyperspace you need to build indexes & maintain them.

[ZOrder](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#z-ordering-multi-dimensional-clustering) is a different functionality - it optimizes placement of the data, so there is a higher probability that data that are used often together are really placed together, so you'll read less files.  Hyperspace doesn't have that - it just indexes data, and placement of the data is defined by the underlying file format.

P.S. Here is the good [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/07/31/processing-petabytes-of-data-in-seconds-with-databricks-delta.html) from Databricks about Data Skipping and ZOreder.

Comment: Do you a reference for : "But on Databricks, indexing of data happens automatically when they are written" ? I am not sure if this is necessarily true.

Comment: The statistics is collected automatically on first N columns (configurable, 32 by default). The same for bloom filters